# How to iterate through any array of letters and animate through each letter in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iterator, closures

I am trying to create a typewriter effect animate so when I type into the input box, a new message is displayed and animates.

I tried having a global char variable to go through each element of the array, but when I would pass another other array of letters, after typing text into the input box, the h1 would not be overwritten.

This was my attempt at that

```
    // wrap each letter in output in a span 
    function createInduvidualLetterSpans(letterArr) {
    if (textEl.innerHTML) {
        textEl.innerHTML = ''
    }

    for (const letter of letterArr) {
        const letterEl = document.createElement('span')
        letterEl.textContent = letter
        textEl.appendChild(letterEl)
    }
    return textEl
    }

    // animate each letter
    let char = 0

    function displayChars() {
    const span = textEl.querySelectorAll('span')[char]
    span.classList.add('load')
    char++
    if (char == textArr.length) {
        complete()
        return
    }
    }

    function complete() {
    clearInterval(timer)
    timer = null
    }

    createInduvidualLetterSpans(textArr)
    let timer = setInterval(displayChars, 10)
```

My next attempt was to try iterators and closure. I've just been reading up on those ideas and imeditly thought this would be a perfect use case for them. However, I got the text to animate forward, but I am getting a

`span is unidentified`
error and I am not sure why.

```js
//turn text into an array of letters
const textEl = document.querySelector('h1')

const textArr = textEl.textContent.split('')
const explore = 'Your lack of desire has lead you towards a life of bordeom and dread. [[GAME OVER]]'.split('')

const userInput = document.getElementById('user-input')
textEl.textContent = ''

// iterator fn
function iterator(arr) {
    let count = 0
    
    const inner = {
        next: function () {
            const el = arr[count]
            count++
            arr[count] == undefined ? done = true : done = false
            return {
                value: el,
                done
            }
        },
        createSpan: function (letterArr) {
            textEl.textContent = ''
            for (const letter of letterArr) {
                const letterEl = document.createElement('span')
                letterEl.textContent = letter
                textEl.appendChild(letterEl)
            }
        },
        animateEachLetter: function () {
            const span = textEl.querySelectorAll('span')[count]
            span.classList.add('load')
            count++
            arr[count] == undefined ? done = true : done = false
        }

    }
    return inner
}

const it = iterator(explore);
it.createSpan(explore)

const exploreRoom = () => {
    it.createSpan(explore)
}
exploreRoom()

setInterval(it.animateEachLetter, 10)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  max-width: 100%;
}

span {
  opacity: 0;
}

span.load {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <h1>You wake, confused and disoriented. Something just does not feel quite right. You reach over to the night stand, find a pair of glasses, put them on (even though you do not wear glasses and stand up. Do you explore the room or go back to bed?</h1>

  <form id="user-input">
    <input id="user-text" class="input" type="text" name="text" autofocus>
  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
setInterval(it.animateEachLetter, 10)
```

and

```
    animateEachLetter: function () {
        const span = textEl.querySelectorAll('span')[count]
        span.classList.add('load')
        count++
        arr[count] == undefined ? done = true : done = false
    }
```

you're calling `animateEachLetter` and trying to find `span`, change its class, and increment the count regardless. It sounds like you just need to check whether such a span exists first - if it doesn't, clear the interval. The iterator protocol makes things much more confusing than they need to be for this, you might consider removing it completely.

Also, your `animateEachLetter` actually animates a *single* letter, not *each* letter. Consider having an `animateEachLetter` method which actually animates every letter, which calls a *different* method (one which runs in the interval) which animates *one* letter:

```js
const textEl = document.querySelector('h1');
const textArr = textEl.textContent.split('');
const explore = 'Your lack of desire has lead you towards a life of bordeom and dread. [[GAME OVER]]'.split('');
const userInput = document.getElementById('user-input');

function makeAnimator(arr) {
  let count = 0;

  return {
    createSpan: function(letterArr) {
      textEl.textContent = '';
      for (const letter of letterArr) {
        const letterEl = document.createElement('span');
        letterEl.textContent = letter;
        textEl.appendChild(letterEl);
      }
    },
    animateEachLetter(ms) {
      this.interval = setInterval(() => this.animateOneLetter(), ms);
    },
    animateOneLetter() {
      const span = textEl.querySelectorAll('span')[count];
      if (!span) {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        return;
      }
      span.classList.add('load')
      count++
      arr[count] == undefined ? done = true : done = false
    }

  };
}

const animator = makeAnimator(explore);
animator.createSpan(explore)
animator.animateEachLetter(20);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  max-width: 100%;
}

span {
  opacity: 0;
}

span.load {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <h1>You wake, confused and disoriented. Something just does not feel quite right. You reach over to the night stand, find a pair of glasses, put them on (even though you do not wear glasses and stand up. Do you explore the room or go back to bed?</h1>

  <form id="user-input">
    <input id="user-text" class="input" type="text" name="text" autofocus>
  </form>

</div>
```